# Multiple File Upload From React Native Using Multer Not Completing

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, upload, multer

I am building an application in React Native for MacOS that involves uploading files from the frontend to a server I built which then process the files and passes them onto another API. I am using React Native FS, FormData, and fetch to get the files and pass them on to my backend, and I am using multer on my backend Express app to receive the files as form data and store them to be sent to the API. The relevant code is shown below:

RN Component Handling File Uploads

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Pressable, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

interface UploadButtonProps {
  disabled: boolean;
  dirName: string;
  channel: string; // Add this prop
}

const UploadButton: React.FC<UploadButtonProps> = ({
  disabled,
  dirName,
  channel,
}) => {
  const [buttonColor, setButtonColor] = useState<string>('#2d2d2d');

  useEffect(() => {
    setButtonColor(disabled ? '#2d2d2d' : '#007AFF');
  }, [disabled]);

  const handlePress = async (): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      if (dirName /*&& channel*/) {
        const files = await RNFS.readDir(dirName);
        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('channel', channel);

        for (let file of files) {
          if (file.isFile() && file.name.endsWith('.JPG' || '.jpg')) {
            formData.append('files', {
              uri: 'file://' + file.path,
              type: 'image/jpeg',
              name: file.name,
            });
          }
        }

        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/uploadFiles', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData,
        }); console.log(response);

        if (response.ok) {
          console.log('Upload successful!');
          console.log(await response.text());
        } else {
          console.log('Upload failed!');
        }
      } else {
        console.log('Please select both a folder and a channel.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error uploading file:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Pressable
      style={[styles.button, {backgroundColor: buttonColor}]}
      onPress={handlePress}>
      <Text style={styles.baseText}>Upload</Text>
    </Pressable>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    marginTop: 200,
    width: 300,
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: '#2d2d2d',
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 10,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 1},
    shadowOpacity: 0.4,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 1,
  },

  baseText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: 'System',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

export default UploadButton;
```

Multer Config File:

```
import multer from 'multer';
import path from 'path';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, path.join(__dirname, '../uploads'));
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

export const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

API Routes

```
import express, { Router } from 'express';
import { getChannels, uploadFiles } from '../Controllers/api.controllers';
import { upload } from '../Middleware/multerConfig';

const router: Router = express.Router();

// Attach HTTP methods to the various API routes:
router.get('/getChannels', getChannels);
router.post('/uploadFiles', upload.array('files'), uploadFiles);

export default router;
```

API Controller

```
import express from 'express';
import SlackBot from '../Models/slackbot';

export const getChannels = async (request: express.Request, response: express.Response) => {
    try {
        const slackbot = new SlackBot();
        const channels = await slackbot.getChannels();
        response.status(200).json(channels);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error fetching channels: ${error}`);
        response.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to retrieve channels' });
    }
  };

  export const uploadFiles = async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    const { channel } = req.body;
    const files = req.files;
    console.log(files); // Logging shows all the files in the request.

    // Calculate total file upload size in KB which comes out to be ~173.51 kB
    let totalSizeInKB = 0;
    let i = 0;
    files.forEach((file: any) => {
      totalSizeInKB += file.size / 1024;
    });
    console.log(`Total file upload size: ${totalSizeInKB.toFixed(2)} KB`);
```

The application allows users to select a directory and all images with a .jpg or .JPG extension will be appended to the form data object. I am using a set of test images, and when I execute the code, the request is received, but the files are not all present in the upload folder created to store the files processed by multer. It seems as though a random amount of files (5-7 out of 19) are actually processed and stored, even though the data and uri's for all the files are present in the request.

I cannot seem to figure out the reason as to why the files are not all being processed/upload. From the error handling in the React Native Component, I get the following error:

> "Error uploading file: [TypeError: Network request failed]"

but I have tried on various networks, all with good speeds and encountered the same issues.

I have tried changing the max request size for Express in case it was being limited there, and have tried to implement base64 encoding but encountered the same issues.

I am just trying to figure out if my implementation of multer incorrect, or maybe there is some limitation that I could not find in the documentation. Thanks in advance for any help.